# convert data frame column to factor

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I want just to convert two columns of a data frame to factors.
I use the apply function but the result is characters, not factors.
Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

```
aa <- c(1,2,3,4)
bb <- c(6,7,8,9)
xx <- data.frame(aa, bb)
xx

yy <- apply(xx, 2, function(xx) as.factor(xx))
#      aa  bb 
# [1,] "1" "6"
# [2,] "2" "7"
# [3,] "3" "8"
# [4,] "4" "9"
```

When I am implementing the same to a stand alone vector, it works:

```
nn <- c(1,2,3,4)
mm <- as.factor(nn)
mm
```

Comment: `apply` is returning a matrix, which requires that all elements be the same type.  Try using `as.data.frame(lapply(xx, factor))`.

Comment: yes, it works. Please make it an answer. It is not obvious that this must be done via a list.

Comment: @akrun reopening this dupe is just childish behaviour. I can't close all the dupes on SO. If you can, you are welcome to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` is usually not suitable for data.frames, because it returns a matrix. You could use `lapply` instead:

```
yy <- data.frame(lapply(xx, as.factor))
str(yy)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ aa: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4
# $ bb: Factor w/ 4 levels "6","7","8","9": 1 2 3 4
```

I assume you realize you could also just do

```
xx <- data.frame(aa = as.factor(aa), bb = as.factor(bb))
```

Comment: `xx[] <- lapply(xx, factor)` will be more general for your second option.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
library(dplyr)
yy = xx %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor))
```

This applies `as.factor` to each column in `xx`.

Comment: You could also do `xx %<>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor))` using the `magrittr` package in order to update `xx` without creating `yy`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(xx)[, lapply(.SD, as.factor)]
```

Comment: Probably `for (j in names(xx)) set(xx, j = j, value = factor(xx[[j]]))` will be better.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, it would be, but for 2 columns, the `lapply` is more readable.